# How is it decided who led each lap?

Tags: formula-1

How is it decided who led each lap of an F1 race?

For example, consider that Hamilton is P1 and Bottas is P2 at the start of the first lap. Towards the end of the lap, Bottas overtakes Hamilton and takes P1. Would Hamilton be considered to have led the first lap because he was leading for most of it, or would Bottas be considered to have led the first lap because he was leading at the end of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot find a reference to it in the sporting regulations, but the lap leader is simply whoever crosses the finish line first for that lap.

In your example, Bottas would be scored as the lap leader for lap 1 by being the first driver to have crossed the finish line one time.